# SSO and Excel connector

Tags: apex, single-sign-on, excel, office-connect

Is there a way to login from an excel connector using SSO credentials? 
I did see the post here https://code.google.com/p/excel-connector/issues/detail?id=31 requesting to add SSO for excel connector. Have things changed in the near future,has some come up with alternatives.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Can someone help please :/, Is there a workaround/ alternative.Thanks

Comment: I don't believe it works, I've been able to use the My Domain URL with DataLoader, if that helps, but needed to enter the username / password. SSO via the API will need a fair amount of refactoring.

Comment: I was hearing a no from all over, thought there was an alternative/ workaround :(.